# Electron removing the Top Menu Bar completely?

Tags: electron

I'm new to Electron, and have basic knowledge of JavaScript, how does one completely remove the menu bar from Electron apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to make a BrowserWindow you could make it FrameLess by -> frame: false

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, frame: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this function: setMenuBarVisibility

refer to: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetmenubarvisibilityvisible-windows-linux